# Transfer money from China to India

Tags: india, money-transfer, dtaa, china

I came to China on 09th September, 2015. My work permit is valid upto 15th September, 2016. I get my salary after tax-deduction as per taxation in China. My question is how can I send money to my account in India without paying double taxation. I don't have any knowledge of foreign money transfer policies. Should I have to pay tax as an Indian tax-payee citizen for the current financial year?

Comment: chances are yes, but you might want to check with a tax professional in India and explain the situation to get a better picture of how it will affect you

Answer (score 1):

For the financial year 1 April 2015 to 31 March 2016, as you will be spending more than 182 days you would be deemed Non-Resident Indian for tax purposes. Hence the income you earn outside India would be tax free in India.

You can transfer funds into India or keep it in China, this does not change the tax situation.

Ensure that you have converted your Savings accounts in India as NRO and opened an NRE account.